# Add Value column using another column as Key

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Hopefully the table itself states the problem. Essentially with the `Type` column on the left, is it possible to add a unique code/value column using `Type` as a hash key/set based on the appearance orders of the types:

```
Type | Code
-----------
ADA  |    1
ADA  |    1
BIM  |    2
BIM  |    2
CUR  |    3
BIM  |    2
DEQ  |    4
ADA  |    1
...  |  ...
```

We can't simply hard-code the conversion as each time there's arbitrary number of `Type`s.

Comment: so, each type has to be assigned a unique value, no matter how many times it appears in the table. is that correct?

Comment: @vkp that's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select type, dense_rank() over (order by type) as code
from t;
```

However, I would advise you to create another table and to use that:

```
create table Types as (
    select row_number() over (order by type) as TypeId,
           type
    from t
    group by type;
```

Then, join that in:

```
select t.type, tt.TypeId
from t join
     types tt
     on t.type = tt.type;
```

Comment: Elegant! Works like a charm! Thanks again, Gordon!